# Por que Tree não vem com um valor, mas sim com o nome do objeto em memória?

Tags: java, primefaces

[Imagem do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKxnR.png)

## Managed Bean

```
package com.algaworks.erp.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

import com.algaworks.erp.model.Categoria;
import com.algaworks.erp.repository.Categorias;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ConsultaCategoriaBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject private Categorias categorias;

    /**
     * interface do primefaces
     * 1º nível de nó
     * treenode que não aparece na arvore, é um no invisivel
     */
    private TreeNode raiz; 

    public void consultar(){
        List<Categoria> categoriasRaizes = categorias.raizes();
        this.raiz = new DefaultTreeNode("Raiz", null);
        adicionarNos(categoriasRaizes,this.raiz);

    }

    private void adicionarNos(List<Categoria> categorias, TreeNode pai){
        /**
         * Iterando na lista e adicionar 
         */
        for(Categoria categoria : categorias){

            /**Instanciando um novo nó
             * passando o valor(categoria), pai
             * no - pai - categoria atual
             */
            TreeNode no = new DefaultTreeNode(categorias, pai);
            //raiz.getChildren().add(no);

            /**chamar adicionandoNos recursivamente passsando o valor(categoria.getSubcategorias(), pai(no))
             * para carregar subcategorias para a categoria atual (no)
             * Consulta lazy para subCategorias
             */
            adicionarNos(categoria.getSubcategorias(), no);
        }
    }

    public TreeNode getRaiz() {
        return raiz;
    }![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]

}
```

## Facelet

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- DEFINICAO DO TEMPLATE A SER UTILIZADO E IMPORTACAO DAS NAMESPACES-->
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/Layout.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
<!-- ação que sera chamada toda vez que a view for carregada -->
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewAction action="#{consultaCategoriaBean.consultar}" />
        </f:metadata>


O que for escrito fora do dine nao sera exibido     
        <!-- DEFINICAO DO CORPO -->
    <ui:define name="corpo">
        <h1>Componente Tree Primefaces</h1>

        <h:form id="frmCategorias">
            <p:tree value="#{consultaCategoriaBean.raiz}" 
                    var="cat" 
                    dynamic="true"
                    style="width:700px; height:400px">
                <p:treeNode>
                    <h:outputText value="#{cat}" />
                </p:treeNode>
            </p:tree>
        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está sendo exibido é o resultado do método `toString` dos objetos colocados na árvore, por causa do seguinte trecho:

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{cat}" />
```

O código acima instrui o JSF a converter um objeto `Categoria` para texto e imprimir o resultado.

Se quiser imprimir um atributo específico, pode fazer algo assim:

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{cat.descricao}" />
```

Então se a classe `Categoria` tiver um método `String getDescricao()`, o mesmo será invocado e o valor retornado exibido na sua página.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela indicação, realizei a alteração <h:outputText value="#{cat.descricao}" /> mas, deu uma exeption.

Comment: @Carl O objeto tem que ter uma propriedade `descricao` ou equivalente. Qual a exception?

Answer (score 0):

muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Consegui encontrar o erro.

No método adicionarNos ao invés de passar objeto categoria eu estava passando List categorias.

```
   //errado
    TreeNode no = new DefaultTreeNode(categorias, pai);

    //correto
    TreeNode no = new DefaultTreeNode(categoria, pai);
```